# Makefile dealing with header files

Tags: gcc, makefile, c-header

The following is my makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -O3
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
EXES = $(patsubst %.c,%,$(SRCS))
.c.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
SRC_CODE=\
        file1.c\
        file2.c\
        file.h
SOFI2D_OBJ=$(SRC_CODE:%.c=%.o)
sofi2D: $(SOFI2D_OBJ)
        $(CC) $^ -o $@
clean:
        rm -rf *.o *.o* *~ $(EXES)   
all: clean sofi2D
```

I wonder how the header file (.h) plays a role in the compilation? Because all the operations are on .c files...

Comment: I think since the header file (.h) is included in the source code (.c), it will automatically find the header file in the same content while compiling. That's why we don't need to worry about header files... Am I right?

Comment: If the header is in the working directory (where you execute `make`) the compiler will find it. But if you compile and then change the header, Make will not know that the binaries are out of date, not unless you write that into the makefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header file is used by the C compiler, not make.

If you want the .c files to be rebuilt if `file.h` changes, then you need to change the definition of `SRC_CODE`:

```
SRC_CODE = file1.c file2.c
$(SRC_CODE): file.h
```

Comment: Thank you @James McPherson . This seems to make things complicated. Can I just "make clean" and run my makefile again? So whatever modification (.h or .c) happens, everything will be rebuilt and recompiled... Am I right?

Comment: If you `make clean` without changing the dependency specification then the next `make` will do exactly as the last. Even if you've changed the .h file. If you're going to make further changes to your .h file and want those reflected in the compilation, then you need to make changes like I suggested.