# Makefile doesnt create final executable

Tags: c, makefile

I have this makefile

```
CFLAGS=-g
LDFLAGS=-g

exec: fluxo.o validar.o ficheiroParaMemoria.o

fluxo.o: fluxo.c

validar.o: validar.c validar.h

ficheiroParaMemoria.o: ficheiroParaMemoria.c ficheiroParaMemoria.h

clean:
    rm -f run *.o
```

It creates the 3 .o files, but it's not creating the executable. Fluxo.c has main and nothing else.
INvisibles show nothing but endline at the end of each line and a tabe before the clean command

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: Header files should be listed as prerequisites of object files, since, if a header file changes, the object file should be rebuilt. The rules should be set so they are not listed directly on the compile command line, but they should participate in dependency analysis. Sometimes this is done by automatically generating the dependencies, so they appear in auxiliary files rather than the main makefile, but they should be listed one way or another.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: make has built-in default rules, so explicit rules are not needed for simple projects. From memory (on mobile now), I think that may apply for the compile commands but not the link to make the executable, so an explicit command may be needed for that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil right, just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49393912/makefile-dealing-with-header-files).

Comment: @EricPostpischil so the problem is that there's no file named exec.o so make doesn't know what to do with the `exec` rule?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca seems to be the problem... Fixed it by calling "exec" "fluxo" instead

Comment: The Makefile should have the statement: `.PHONY: clean`  the command beginning with `exec:` needs a tabbed line below it the includes something like: `$(cc) %$^ -o %$<`   Then when compiling, the warnings should not be suppressed, so the `CFLAGS` should be something like: `CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu11`  (for `gcc` compiler/linker)

Comment: changing `exec` to `fluxo` will only link the `fluxo.o` file, not the other object files

Answer (score 1):

Sorry i dont understand your Makefile, but here is works Makefile from my project:

```
CC = gcc
FLAGS = -std=c99
DEST_PATH = "./bin/main"


all: clean main.o Smtp.o Base64.o
    $(CC) build/*.o -o $(DEST_PATH) $(FLAGS)

main.o: src/main.cpp src/Service/Smtp.hpp
    $(CC) src/main.cpp -c -o build/main.o $(FLAGS)

Smtp.o: src/Service/Smtp.cpp src/Service/Smtp.hpp
    $(CC) src/Service/Smtp.cpp -c -o build/Smtp.o $(FLAGS)

Base64.o: src/Service/Base64.cpp src/Service/Base64.hpp
    $(CC) src/Service/Base64.cpp -c -o build/Base64.o $(FLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f build/*
```

`-c` flag create object file(.o).
In you example i dont see any real command except `rm`.
Hope this help.

Comment: I've used this exact formula for other projects, and it always worked... And as I said, the .o files are created

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Needed to change the name "exec" to "fluxo" because that contains the main function

Answer (score 0):

Your Makefile doesn't contain any rules to build an executable. This rule is the closest - it creates a dependency between those 3 object files and a target called "exec".

```
exec: fluxo.o validar.o ficheiroParaMemoria.o
```

If you want to build "exec" from those 3 object files you need to expand the rule to also include the command to do just that.

```
exec: fluxo.o validar.o ficheiroParaMemoria.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

In the command `$@` is used to indicate the target so would be "exec" in this case. `$^` are the dependencies.

The reason why you don't need to add in commands to build the .o files is that make includes a builtin rule for building .o files from a .c file of the same name. There is also a builtin rule for building an executable from a .o or .c of the same name, but that isn't much use in this case as it wouldn't include the the other 2 .o files

Also, `LDFLAGS` is typically used to specify linking options not compilation options so you don't need the "-g" in it

Comment: '-g' is also a linking option